# Is there something like BeautifulSoup for Android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to find an xml parser that is extremely forgiving.  Like Python's BeautifulSoup.  Is there anything out there?

Comment: What, only -10 points?  You can whack me harder than that can't you?

Comment: While this isn't exactly a detailed question, it seems reasonable enough to me, and is being jumped on unreasonably.

Answer (score 18):

Okay, I found Jsoup.  A Java version of a permissive XML parser like BeautifulSoup.

http://jsoup.org/

I will try that and see how it goes.

thx