# Parsing websites updates and sending them through android app to users

Tags: android, rss, rss-reader

It's required from me to  make an android app that must

1\Displays the cheapest prizes  for some goods  eg car by parsing them from some commercial   web sites  ascending .

2\Alerts   users with the updates in those web sites

I saw  some android apps  doing like  this tasks (they enable users to be the first to know by sending them push notifications of breaking news events and so on)

for  example Pulse app.

How they do this ? that is my problem

Perhaps  you will advice me using  rss feed but  not all web sites have rss feed
[for just an example this website](http://ksa.hatla2ee.com/en)

please can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I'd probably use python's BeautifulSoup to scour the websites for the data you need, and then I'd store that on my webserver in some easily Java-digestible form like JSON. (BeautifulSoup is a quite powerful screen scraper and there are a lot of examples on web as to how to use it.) Auto update it every 24 hours, or more frequently, depending on your requirements. Your Android app can then regularly query this data, and then generate the required notifications, etc. Alternatively, you can use the Android compatible library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165883/is-there-something-like-beautifulsoup-for-android) that's supposedly similar to BeautifulSoup.